# Smart pointer r-value ref conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to write a smart pointer that can easily upcast, but I'm running into trouble with upcasting r-value references. Consider the following:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class SmartPtr
{
    T* impl_;

public:
    // ...

    template<typename U>
    operator SmartPtr<U>&&() &&
    {
        U* u = impl_; // Fail with a nice error message if T* isn't implicitly convertable to U*;
        return reinterpret_cast<SmartPtr<U>&&>(*this);
    }

    // ...
};

struct A {};
struct B : public A {};

int main()
{
    SmartPtr<B> pb;
    SmartPtr<A>&& pa = std::move(pb);
}
```

This fails in Visual C++ 2015 with the following error message:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'SmartPtr<B>' to 'SmartPtr<A> &&'
note: Reason: cannot convert from 'SmartPtr<B>' to 'SmartPtr<A>'
note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Note: this works in Clang 3.4 and simpler versions (e.g. a wrapper class being implicitly convertible to an r-value-ref of the inner value) work in Visual Studio 2015.

Should what I'm trying to do work according to the standard? Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<SmartPtr<U>&&>(*this)` This makes no sense. Informally, it is not generally the case that, after `U* u = impl_`, `u` and `impl_` refer to the same address, are represented by the same bit pattern. So basically, even if you find a way to ram this cast through, this approach is not going to work. Just return `SmartPtr<U>` by value.

Comment: I had briefly considered that but dismissed it as something that only happens with multiple inheritance, which I'm not doing in my project. Are there other cases I'm not thinking of?

I don't think the error I'm seeing is related to that, however, since the non-r-value-ref version works as expected. Let me see if I can come up with an example without any unsafe casts.

Comment: `only happens with multiple inheritance` False. It would also happen in a case like this: `class A {}; class B : public A { virtual void f() {} };`

Comment: Anyway, if you insist on living dangerously, I suspect something like this would "work": `return std::move(*reinterpret_cast<SmartPtr<U>*>(this));`

Comment: Nope, exact same error. I don't insist on living dangerously. This is now more of a curiosity than a troubleshooting question.